# Passing data between states PHP

Tags: php, rest

So I am using Limonade PHP which has a RESTful design which emulates PUT, POST, DELETE routes for create, update, delete.

I am trying to develop some form validation which is going well. The major problem I am facing though is how to return my filtered data (which has failed validation) back to repopulate the create or edit form.

How would this be done? I currently have for creating a page:

```
/admin/page/new -> GET function

/admin/page -> POST function
+ validate
    + pass, update db
    + fail, add errors to flash, redirect to /admin/page/mew
```

It all falls down as I do not know how to populate the /admin/page/new with the invalid, but filtered data.

Comment: Do you have to redirect on failure? Could you simply output the form again on failure w/o redirect?

Comment: @outis, the main thing with that is i would have the repeat the form code which is already called using the GET route. if you can explain a way round i am all ears.

Comment: it's a little unwieldy to post in a comment, so look to my answer below.

Comment: Taking a closer look at the `/admin/page/new` URL, it doesn't look completely RESTful, as `new` is a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used a session to carry the data to /admin/page/new?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

edit:
I just found this article: http://www.recessframework.org/page/towards-restful-php-5-basic-tips which recommends using a cookie over $_SESSION.  It doesn't elaborate on why, but either one will achieve the result you want.

Comment: is that the standard way to do it? i did think of using that.

Comment: IDK about standard, but sessions or a cookie were the first solutions that came to my mind for passing data between states.

Comment: Just added an article I found to my answer.  Tip #4 recommends using a cookie instead actually.

Comment: Sessions aren't RESTful. If that requirement can be relaxed, then sessions are a possibility.

Comment: @outis i think the using cookies is out of my learning scope at the moment. sessions will work wonderfully. once i have finished my app however i will certainly be looking at using cookies to create a stateless app.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data back to the redirected page, you either need to use session or litter the request with get vars for each element (not nice to look at, not nice for bookmarking, wouldn't suggest it).

I'd guess that **'add errors to flash' is using a session var** (not familiar with Limonade).

Another alternative would be **submitting the form with an AJAX call**, then the form data wouldn't even change on an error.

Of course, you would still need a non-AJAX method working for backwards compatibility.

*Update*: [Limonade Source](http://github.com/sofadesign/limonade/blob/master/lib/limonade.php) confirms `flash()` uses `$_SESSION`. So you're already using session vars.

Comment: @tim, yep now using sessions and all is wonderful. not up to standard to work out ajax yet, but it is functionality i want to add once i have the app finished. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the form without redirecting. Put the form in a script containing no other HTML elements. Have it set the value of any form input given in `$_POST` (after calling `htmlspecialchars` with the appropriate quote style). Include the form script in other scripts where appropriate.

In your utility functions:

```
function passthruFormInput($name) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
      echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$name], ENT_QUOTES); 
    }
}
```

newForm.php (or whatever you want to call it):

```
<form action="..." method="POST" onsubmit="...(client side validation function)...">
    ...
    <input name="foo" value="<?php passthruFormInput('foo'); ?>"/>
    ...
</form>
```

If you generate the form dynamically, adapt the above to match. A few things feel off about this implementation and approach, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Leaving the form script publicly accessible may not be a security problem, but it should either be outside the document root hierarchy or in a branch protected with [`ORDER Allow,Deny`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#rewrite). It should probably go with the views.

Comment: i see what you mean. i have this architecture already. unfortunately i think that method would break the functionality of the framework (limonade-php.net), that i am using. cheers for the input though.